read-the-docs build has blank html for some pages
We use read-the-docs and sphinx to build documentation for a package hosted on GitHub. The documentation includes .ipynb files (Python notebooks) which are rendered as HTML on the readthedocs web page. Recently, readthedocs builds have succeeded, but some HTML pages corresponding to the .ipynb notebooks are completely empty. I cannot find any indication in the debugging log of why this might happen, and there are other notebooks with similar content that succeed. When I build the docs locally on my computer, the HTML renderings of the notebooks are fine.
How can I debug why I'm getting empty HTML pages?
Full build log: https://app.readthedocs.org/projects/opensoundscape/builds/25880108/
Documentation: https://opensoundscape.org/en/v0.11.0/
Example of a notebook that renders as blank HTML page https://opensoundscape.org/en/v0.11.0/tutorials/audio.html
The notebook .ipynb file is present:
https://opensoundscape.org/en/v0.11.0/tutorials/audio.ipynb
Furthermore, even when we look back at older "versions of the documentation that were originally built successfully, e.g.
https://opensoundscape.org/en/v0.9.0/tutorials/audio_and_spectrogram.html
they are now blank as well!
However, we know that these were originally built and rendered successfully as HTML:
https://web.archive.org/web/20230921221405/https://opensoundscape.org/en/v0.9.0/tutorials/audio_and_spectrogram.html
Therefore, there seems to have been some change in readthedocs that is causing these html-rendered notebooks to be blank when hosted on the website.
Any ideas for how to address this would be greatly appreciated.

I can confirm that it's not just you. I too have an example https://docs.maap-project.org/en/latest/science/HLS/HLSL30.html
But that's the only notebook that vanished. Is it all the notebooks on your site or just some?
With web developer tools open I see a gpc.json file that contains a 404 page not found. This seems like a bug we should report to https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues

Asked in ReadTheDocs Gitter channel, it's a bug with large files.
"So far, two solutions are to output image files instead of inlining the images, or you might be able to disable Addons temporarily"

It's a bug in the new Add-On implementation that occurs with pages with big memory footprints, often due to embedded images (which is the default for a ipynb noetbook)
https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/11693
Suggested workarounds from the ticket:

Temporarily, if you are hitting this error you can either disable
Addons for your project or try to reduce the response size for the
page. If you are using a notebook, you could try to output image as
files instead of using inline data in the HTML for the images.


Thanks, I'll try this but how would I use files rather than inline data for HTML pages that are automatically built from .ipynb files using nbsphinx? I wasn't able to find any relevant settings on the nbsphinx documentation

Sam, theres' no settings to change. All the changes are in the notebook itself, use markdown to reference images not in the notebook, and clear the cell outputs that they mimic. Here's an example PR doing so https://github.com/MAAP-Project/maap-documentation/pull/445/files

In our case, the figures are matplotlib.pyplot figures generated by the code itself
